# Algorithm to detect and fix errors/spikes in signal

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, math, sequence, error-correction

I have a sequence of characters. The characters are ordered in chronological order. I am looking for an algorithm to group the sequence and remove errors in the data. I am having an hard time to explain in words/maths what the requirement of fixing the sequence is but something like "arrange the sequences to the most probable uninterrupted sequence of character group" and minimum sequence length should be a setting. Below I am trying to visualize by some examples what I mean (3 chars minimum):

AAACCAACA =>
AAAAAAAAA

ACACAAAAA =>
AAAAAAAAA

AYYYYYYYA =>
YYYYYYYYY

YYYYAAYYY =>
YYYYYYYYY

AYAYAYYYY =>
YYYYYYYYY

And for longer sequences it becomes a little more tricky

AYAYAYAYAAAAAAAAAAYAYYYYYYYYYYYYYY =>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

HTHTTHHHTTHHH => 
TTTTTHHHHHHHH

TTOAOAOOAATTA =>
OOOOOOOOAAAAA

This is bit tricky because even thought the 3 O's aren't directly next to each other, they are still the most probable uninterrupted sequence of characters.

Does anyone know of any algorithm (Machine learning?) or similar (term of this problem, problem name) that can do this type of error-code correction?

Comment: What words are you saying in your head when you read `=>`?

Comment: "Filters to", "removes noise to" or "transforms to".

Comment: So, in your first example, how do you know the `C`s are errors? Are these transmission errors where a single bit error is more likely than double bit errors?

Comment: Because its only 2 consecutive C's and the most likely unbroken sequence are only A's. C's represents spikes/errors/error samples.

Comment: @MarkSetchell any more input? really appreciate if you could lead me into some terminology of what I could research into. Or propose an algorithm for this kind of error-detection fix.

Comment: Not sure there is even a discernible pattern here. The outcome seems to depend how many characters you consider to be likely to be a chain of constant letters. Do you have some ground truth of what the *"correct"* answer is?

Comment: "The outcome seems to depend how many characters you consider to be likely to be a chain of constant letters" - this is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @MarkSetchell The ground truth would be like you said, trying to find the chain of constant letters (and take in account to spikes/errors and fix them)

Comment: If you are reading "=>" as "filters to" or "removes noise", perhaps look at some noise filtering algorithms as a starting point.